# git 2.17 fails to automerge

Tags: git, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution, git-merge-conflict

I recently updated git from 2.9 to 2.17. Now automerge fails almost all the time. For example, on one occasion I added some code in a file (let's call it `x.py`) in `master`. Then, when I tried to merge `master` into another branch (call it `b`), automerge failed to resolve conflicts in `x.py`, despite that the two versions of the file were exactly the same before my additions and the file `x.py` was modified only in `master`. I manually resolved the conflict and committed. However, later when I made changes in `master` in different files (without modifying `x.py`) and tried to automerge `master` into the same branch `b`, `x.py` gave a conflict. I checked and the problem turned out to be that git failed to recognize that the changes in `x.py` in `b` from my manual merge conflict resolution from the first time were exactly the same as the additions I had in `x.py` in `master`. Specifically, the code that I had initially added in `x.py` on `master` was now duplicated in the file.

Furthermore, if I resolve a conflict after merging `master` into `y`, the next time the exact same conflict pops up and I have to resolve it again.

Any suggestions what might be the cause of this? Has there been some major change in automerging since git 2.9?

Comment: Have you tried to delete your local repo and start 'fresh' clone with 2.17?

Comment: Try setting up a minimal example of a repo that has this problem. Host it on GitHub or just give a list of commands to set up the repo

Comment: It’s be good to see the actual error message

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I tried starting with a fresh clone but no change. The actual error message is `Auto-merging x
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in x
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.`

Comment: I tried setting up a simple example which reproduces the problem, but I cannot get git to reproduce the problem. Not really sure what to do now. I keep getting the problem in my original repo.

Comment: It somehow fixed itself now. I think the problem was somehow related to the fact that I was only changing a particular set of files. When I made a commit which had changes in a new set of files, it somehow fixed itself.